# Generating multidimensional data

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, shapes

Does R have a package for generating random numbers in multi-dimensional space? For example, suppose I want to generate 1000 points inside a cuboid or a sphere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also check out the copula package.  This will generate data within a cube/hypercube with uniform margins, but with correlation structures that you set.  The generated variables can then be transformed to represent other shapes, but still with relations other than independent.

If you want more complex shapes but are happy with uniform and idependent within the shape then you can just do rejection sampling:  generate data within a cube that contains your shape, then test if the points are within your shape, reject them if not, then keep doing this until there are enough points.

Comment: I fail to see how you could use copulas to generate random points in an n-dimensional space, bound by certain limits. The ellipsoid copula for example doesn't have a uniform distribution within at all, it is based on the multivariate normal (or t) distribution. One should be very careful when using this -great- package, and know that what comes out is exactly what one thinks it is. I wouldn't use it for this purpose. Rejection sampling is a whole different matter, that's a perfectly fine solution.

Answer (score 16):

I have some functions for hypercube and n-sphere selection that generate dataframes with cartesian coordinates and guarantee a uniform distribution through the hypercube or n-sphere for an arbitrary amount of dimensions :

```
GenerateCubiclePoints <- function(nrPoints,nrDim,center=rep(0,nrDim),l=1){

    x <-  matrix(runif(nrPoints*nrDim,-1,1),ncol=nrDim)
    x <-  as.data.frame(
            t(apply(x*(l/2),1,'+',center))
          )
    names(x) <- make.names(seq_len(nrDim))
    x
}
```

is in a cube/hypercube of `nrDim` dimensions with a `center` and `l` the length of one side.

For an n-sphere with `nrDim` dimensions, you can do something similar, where `r` is the radius :

```
GenerateSpherePoints <- function(nrPoints,nrDim,center=rep(0,nrDim),r=1){
    #generate the polar coordinates!
    x <-  matrix(runif(nrPoints*nrDim,-pi,pi),ncol=nrDim)
    x[,nrDim] <- x[,nrDim]/2
    #recalculate them to cartesians
    sin.x <- sin(x)
    cos.x <- cos(x)
    cos.x[,nrDim] <- 1  # see the formula for n.spheres

    y <- sapply(1:nrDim, function(i){
        if(i==1){
          cos.x[,1]
        } else {
          cos.x[,i]*apply(sin.x[,1:(i-1),drop=F],1,prod)
        }
    })*sqrt(runif(nrPoints,0,r^2))

    y <-  as.data.frame(
            t(apply(y,1,'+',center))
          )

    names(y) <- make.names(seq_len(nrDim))
    y
}
```

in 2 dimensions, these give :

[image]

From code :

```
 T1 <- GenerateCubiclePoints(10000,2,c(4,3),5)
 T2 <- GenerateSpherePoints(10000,2,c(-5,3),2)
 op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(T1)
 plot(T2)
 par(op)
```

Comment: @Pradeep -- If this answers your question better, you should consider accepting this answer rather than the one you did.

Comment: GenerateSpherePoints() doesn't seem to produce uniform spherical data for more than two dimensions. The marginal distributions are not equal, for one thing. A quick way to simulate uniform spherical data and some diagnostics can be found at https://github.com/ahfoss/n-sphere-simulation

Answer (score 4):

A couple of years ago, I made a package called geozoo.  It is available on CRAN.

```
install.packages("geozoo")
library(geozoo)
```

It has many different functions to produce objects in N-dimensions.

```
p = 4
n = 1000

# Cube with points on it's face.  
# A 3D version would be a box with solid walls and a hollow interior.
cube.face(p)

# Hollow sphere
sphere.hollow(p, n)


# Solid cube
cube.solid.random(p, n)
cube.solid.grid(p, 10) # evenly spaced points

# Solid Sphere
sphere.solid.random(p, n)
sphere.solid.grid(p, 10) # evenly spaced points
```

One of my favorite ones to watch animate is a cube with points along its edges, because it was one of the first objects that I made.  It also gives you a sense of distance between vertices.

```
# Cube with points along it's edges.  
cube.dotline(4)
```

Also, check out the website: http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/~dicook/geometric-data/.  It contains pictures and downloadable data sets.

Hope it meets your needs!

Comment: Thank you very much ll definitely check it out:)

Comment: that package of yours looks promising, thanks for pointing there.

Answer (score 2):

Cuboid:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = runif(1000),
    y = runif(1000),
    z = runif(1000)
)

head(df)

          x           y         z
1 0.7522104 0.579833314 0.7878651
2 0.2846864 0.520284731 0.8435828
3 0.2240340 0.001686003 0.2143208
4 0.4933712 0.250840233 0.4618258
5 0.6749785 0.298335804 0.4494820
6 0.7089414 0.141114804 0.3772317
```

Sphere:

```
df <- data.frame(
    radius = runif(1000),
    inclination = 2*pi*runif(1000),
    azimuth = 2*pi*runif(1000)
)


head(df)

     radius inclination  azimuth
1 0.1233281    5.363530 1.747377
2 0.1872865    5.309806 4.933985
3 0.2371039    5.029894 6.160549
4 0.2438854    2.962975 2.862862
5 0.5300013    3.340892 1.647043
6 0.6972793    4.777056 2.381325
```

Note: edited to include code for sphere

Comment: I want to to generate points within the boundary of a specified shape.. say a cuboid ,cube ,sphere ??.... is there any way to generate such datasets ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.
Say we hope to generate a bunch of 3d points of the form y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)

1. Sample X from multivariate Gaussian with mean zero and covariance matrix R.

   ```
      (x_1, x_2, x_3) ~ Multivariate_Gaussian(u = [0,0,0], R = [[r_11, r_12, r_13],r_21, r_22, r_23], [r_31, r_32, r_33]]
   ```

   You can find a function which generates Multivariate Gaussian samples in an R package.
2. Take the Gaussian cdf of each covariate (phi(x_1) , phi(x_2), phi(x_3)). In this case, phi is the Gaussian cdf of our variables. Ie phi(x_1) = Pr[x <= x_1] By the probability integral transform, these (phi(x_1) , phi(x_2), phi(x_3)) = (u_1, u_2, u_3), will each be uniformly distrubted on [0,1].
3. Then, take the inverse cdf of each uniformly distributed marginal. In other words take the inverse cdf of u_1, u_2, u_3:

   F^{-1}(u_1), F^{-2}(u_2), F^{-3}(u_3) = (y_1, y_2, y_3), where F is the marginal cdf of the distrubution you are trying to sample from.