# How to use Gaussian copula to generate dependent random variables

Tags: r, variables, random, correlation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating multidimensional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016806/generating-multidimensional-data)

I have the correlation matrix and want to generate 500 random variables using the correlation matrix. I was advised to use the Gaussian copula. I looked up online but couldn't find what I want. Thank you. Also, I am trying to do this in R.

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016806/generating-multidimensional-data

Comment: Also, take a look at this blog post by JD Long: http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2010/08/stochastic-simulation-with-copulas-in-r/